# Did Nyaya defend itself and refute Buddhist works

Tags: history, buddhism, nyaya, nyaya-sutra

I heard Nyaya was refuted by Nagarjuna. Did any Nyaya scholars defend their works and refute Buddhism in turn?

Comment: No. Not yet, at least I'm not aware of any stance. Buddhists were one-sided winners in history. Later sects based Hinduism in the history came based on Bhakti and only fought within themselves and own philosophy, calling each other inferior based on scriptures. So, the answer is No.

Comment: Udayana strongly argued against Madhyamaka doctrine from a Nyaya viewpoint in his Nyayakusumanjali.

Comment: Cool anyone else?